# Style Bootstrap Modal with CSS

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am creating a bootstrap modal which will contain an image. Everything works perfectly, but for some reason, I cannot change the styling of the button whatsoever.

I have tried changing the color of the main button by calling its class in CSS. But it is not cooperating.

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <!-- Datatables -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >Prize Plaza</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <embed src="https://ak.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/3998236/thumb/3.jpg" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<style>
.btn.btn-info.btn-lg {
    background-color: red;
}    
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) instead of [`background-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color). It is because there are some other classes like `.btn-info` which have properties like [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) with a linear-gradient value which affects the button and you have not overwritten it.

You might also want to override the border-color property so that the blue border is not being used for red button.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<!-- Datatables -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Prize Plaza</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <embed src="https://ak.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/3998236/thumb/3.jpg" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<style>
  .btn.btn-info.btn-lg {
    background: red;
    border-color: red;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: @m4no how can I manipulate its position? I Want it to be in line with the header and on its right, but when I try to alter its positioning it stays in the top left https://jsfiddle.net/eL4b8dxr/

Comment: @BeerusDev Like this? https://nimb.ws/k49K0N https://jsfiddle.net/ke6Lwtr7/